# Tailwind classes not working in Svelte app

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte

I've continuously been trying for days to get Tailwind classes working with my Svelte project. I followed the exact steps from [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-tailwind-css-with-svelte/) and still nothing works.

Here's the structure of my svelte project:

[image]

The **postcss.config.cjs** code:

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

The **tailwind.config.js** code:

```
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

module.exports = {
  future: {
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
  },
  plugins: [],
  purge: {
    content: ["./src/App.svelte"],
    enabled: production, // disable purge in dev
  },
};
```

in **tailwind.css** file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css -w",
    "build:tailwind": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css",
    "build": "npm run build:tailwind && rollup -c",
    "start": "sirv public",
    "serve": "serve public -p 80",
    "dev": "concurrently \"rollup -c -w\" \"npm run watch:tailwind\""
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/autoprefixer": "^10.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I've looked for so many answers on the web but still nothing works in my laptop...
Tho, the Tailwind CDN works but that's not what I wanted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the best instruction set to go off of. Since you're already using rollup which can handle some of this, adding additional scripts just complicates things. Also, usually (AFAIK‍♂️) the tailwind is imported through a dedicated svelte component.

I would add `tailwindcss` and `autoprefixer` this to your `rollup.config.js`, then you don't need to use `watch:tailwind`

```js
export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // ...
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
        sourceMap: !production,
        postcss: {
          plugins: [require('tailwindcss')(), require('autoprefixer')()],
        },
      }),
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

if you put this into a `Tailwind.svelte` component

```css
<style global>
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
</style>
```

Then you can include via `<Tailwind/>` in your application

Here are some other sources that you might want to look at

- https://dev.to/ardc_overflow/setting-up-svelte-and-tailwind-with-minimal-extra-dependencies-1g5a
- https://github.com/jhanca-vm/Svelte-Tailwind

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing as the original post described but your answer got me curious: what exactly did you mean when said `[...] using rollup which can handle some of this, adding additional scripts just complicates things.`? Do you know if rollup interferes with Tailwind? Could you elaborate a little bit further? Thanks!

Comment: rollup (through plugins) should be able to handle watching for changes to rebuild tailwind stylesheet. Having tailwind run a separate process to watch changes is a more complicated way that could potentially have multiple tailwind builders running in which case there is some potential for conflict, but mostly it's just unnecessary complexity since your single rollup build pipeline can handle that more effectively.